Using existing Test Cycles created in Zephyr Scale via playwright
I am working on with Zephyr Scale integration via Playwright
Suppose I have two existing Test Cycles:

"[Test Environment] Sample Regression Testing" - testCycle ID is ABC-X23
"[Stage Environment] Sample Regression Testing" - testCycle ID is ABC-X24

I have created these existing test cycles in Zephyr Scale.
The thing is, this is my expectation:
Given that I have this configuration (please see config below)
When I run the test
And the test is completed
Then I will use the existing Test Cycle for my tests results to be reflected in Zephyr Scale
The actual thing happened was it creates new test cycles even though I have defined the exact Test Cycle name and key on my end.
Is there a way to just use the existing Test Cycles: [Test Environment] Sample Regression Testing & [Stage Environment] Sample Regression Testing instead of creating new ones automatically?
config file:
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
require('console-stamp')(console, '[HH:MM:ss]');
require('dotenv-flow').config({ path: './helper/env'});

let envi: string;
let testCycleId: string;

envi = process.env.NODE_ENV;
if((process.env.NODE_ENV).toLowerCase() == 'test'){
    envi = 'Test';
    testCycleId = 'X23';
}else if((process.env.NODE_ENV).toLowerCase() == 'stage'){
    envi = 'Stage';
    testCycleId = 'X24';
}


const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  workers: 4,
  testDir: '../tests',
  testMatch: [
    "tests/Sample/RegressionTests/*.ts"
  ],
  timeout: 2000000,
  reporter: [
    ['junit', { outputFile: '../results.xml' }],
    ['playwright-zephyr/lib/src/cloud', {
      projectKey: 'ABC',
      authorizationToken: process.env.ZEPHYR_TOKEN,
      testCycle: {
        key: testCycleId,
        name: '[' + envi + ' Environment] Sample Regression Testing'
      }
    }],
    ['list']
  ],
  use: {
    viewport: { width: 1500, height: 900 },
    actionTimeout: 10000,
    navigationTimeout: 10000,
    headless: true,
    screenshot: "on",
    video: "on",
  },
  expect: {
    timeout: 10000
  },
  globalSetup: "../src/utils/globalSetUp.ts"
};
export default config;

